# efficient JPQL: update entities in @onetomany

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

i have two entities Customer and Order (trivial setters and getters excluded)

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    List<Order> orderList;


}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;

    private boolean paid;

    public Order(Customer customer) {

        this.customer = customer;
        customer.getOrderList().add(this)
    }   
}
```

Now i want to set 'paid = true' for all the orders of a given customer
Below query seem to do the trick, but I get a feeling it is innefficient and the fact that i stored the reverse relationship in Customer.orderList hints that there should be some other way to do this.

```
UPDATE Order o SET o.paid = true WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT c.orderList FROM Customer c WHERE o MEMBER OF c.orderList AND c = :customer)
```

I'm using container managed transactions, glassfish and javaDb. But I'd prefer if improvements could be done in JPA/JPQL domain and not specific to container or db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private id;` ?? missed field type

Add to `@OneToMany` annotation,`cascade = CascadeType.All`

```
Customer entity = entityManager.find(Customer.class, id)   
for (Order order : entity.getOrderList())  
{
   order.setPaid(true);  
}
```

if you are using `cantainer managed transaction` then `true` will be saved to DB

Comment: I've considered this option, but I was thinking batch-update using jpql would be faster, as it wouldn't have to construct the java Entities.

Comment: What type has field 'paid' in database?

Comment: without doing any benchmarks, I think your answer is an improvement to performance. I just thought if batch-update could be used, it would do even better

Comment: In both methods, one query will be send to database. I do not see significant differences